# Stand alone or free application to backup ADAM / AD LDS database files

Tags: backup, adam, ad-lds

Do you know any small standalone and free tool, that can be run in console, to backup / restore ADAM / AD LDS database files (like adamntds.dit, edbres00001.jrs etc.).

I tried to stop ADAM service and copy / paste these files to other location but afterwards I was unable to restore ADAM from these files.

I know I could use on ws 2003 some backup tool that was provided by microsoft but it seems to be unavailable on ws 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 backup actually does disk imaging instead of just backing up the system state which is what you are looking for.

Do you currently have a backup product other then Windows backup?

Comment: No I do not have and I do not want to backup of whole disk (that is what windows backup on ws2008 does ? ). I just need backup of my adam files, I want to migrate them to different machine.

Comment: I think you can still use Windows Backup to get what you are looking for...you just have to drill in to find the service. Try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730941(WS.10).aspx for reference. You could also look at dsdbutil.exe (provided by MSFT) to do you backup and restore. Documented at the same link.

Answer (score 1):

[`dsdbutil`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753151%28WS.10%29.aspx) should do what you need.  Something along these lines:

```
dsdbutil activate instance instancename ifm create full c:\backup\location
```